# Gradle report filesize

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, aar

How can I report or log the filesize of my build via gradle?

I generate an Android .aar library and would like to report it from gradle.

I could use bash, but is there a platform independent way with gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
long kb = file('path/to/file.log').length() / 1024
logger.info "File is ${kb}kb"
```

See

- [logging](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html)
- [Project.file(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#file%28java.lang.Object%29)